# How can I define the output of shortcode attribute value?

Tags: shortcode, customization

I would like to create a shortcode that has predefined output for attribute values.  For example:

```
[shortcode att="value1"]

output = <div id="value1">Predefined content for value1</div>

[shortcode att="value2"]

output = <span id="value2">Predefined content for value2</span>

etc.
```

I'm just not sure how to setup the function with a predefined array of output values.  Ideally the function would look something like this:

```
array(
   value1 = '<div id="value1">',
   value1 = '<div id="value2">'
);
```

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to **Codex:**

```
    
function shortcode_function_name( $atts ) {
   $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
      'attr1' => '',
   ), $atts, 'your-shortcode-name' );

   return '<div id="'.$atts['attr1'].'">Your Predefined Content</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'your-shortcode-name', 'shortcode_function_name' );
```

Adding `[your-shortcode-name attr1="Value1"]` to the content of any post/page will give the following output `<div id="Value1">Your Predefined Content</div>`.

Adding `[your-shortcode-name attr1="Value1"]` to the content of any post/page will give the following output `<div id="Value1">Your Predefined Content</div>`.

etc...

And you can deep by adding the predefined content inside the shortcode, this way you can always change the predefined content inside the shortcode as well.

Hope it helps!